# How to add a button inside a react navigation drawer

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I need to add a logout button in a drawer with the React Navigation drawer tried doing this:

```
<Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Sales" children={CreateHomeStack} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Items" component={ItemsScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
    <Button>
      <Text>LOGOUT</Text>
    </Button>
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

But I get an error saying

> A navigator can only contain screen components...

so how can I add buttons to a Drawer Navigator?

Comment: You can use custom drawer menu. Easy to handle.

Comment: try custom drawer

Answer (score 38):

With respect to 5.x documentation you need to define custom component and override/pass it with drawerContent **props** where you can push your screen routes plus your custom route items.

Here is code how to add custom ReactElement/Component:

```
<Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" drawerContent={props => {
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem label="Logout" onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Login")} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    )
  }}>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
    <Drawer.Screen name="New Project" component={NewProject} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Here you are overriding default drawer container with you component code

This(`<DrawerItemList {...props} />`) line of code render you screen's
And rest is your area where custom code for drawer container will added.

Comment: Great answer. Worked Right away. There are quite complex examples given when i searched. this is just i wanted.

Comment: Make sure to import those components from react-navigation/drawer
-
`import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer' `

Comment: Great answer. This is also the right way to implement LinearGradient to the Drawer Navigator